# Auto Update of DIV is not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I use this script to reload a DIV whose ID is news,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
        <? if ($lim >= 5) 
            $lim = 0;
        else 
            $lim = $lim + 2;

        if ($cnt == 1){
            $lim = 0; 
            $cnt += 1;
        } ?>

        $('#news').load('update.php?lim=<? echo $lim ?>');
    }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

The update.php containts this code to receive the value for lim,

```
$lim=$_GET['lim'];
```

But after every 10 seconds the 'lim' value is sent as 0. I need to update the 'lim' value based on the condition in the script.

I checked in update.php for $lim value using echo command. Always it is 0. What is the bug in my code?

Comment: PHP is serverside and JavaScript is client side ....

Comment: `php` within javascript `setInterval()` !!

Comment: You need to get `$lim` each time from the server with for example an AJAX call. Use that value, as the first value of `$lim` is hardcoded in the javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem a little confused as to what is serverside/clientside. `$lim` is a PHP variable, so is only available on the server side. You need to change your logic over to be javascript. Try this:

```
var lim = <? echo $lim ?>; // assuming lim is always a number this will work.
var cnt = 0; // just guessed at what this should be initially.
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    if (lim >= 5) 
        lim = 0;
    else 
        lim = lim + 2;

    if (cnt == 1){
        lim = 0; 
        cnt += 1;
    }

    $('#news').load('update.php?lim=' + lim);
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

Alternatively you could change the logic to make an AJAX request on each iteration of the timer which passes the `lim` variable to your PHP and receives back the new value.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code is going to be run exactly once, when your page is rendered.  It will never update.  The code in your page looks like this when the page is rendered:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
        $('#news').load('update.php?lim=0');
    }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

If you want to change the value of the lim parameter in your JavaScript, you will have to calculate it in JavaScript.  You can set a starting value with PHP, but again, you'll only get a single value from PHP with code like this.